# Can't push_back move(NonCopyableWithConstField) to vector

Tags: c++, c++11, move

I have a `NonCopyable` class (due to its `unique_ptr` field). I want to create a vector of NonCopyable elements but the following code wouldn't compile

```
    NonCopyable nc;
    vector<NonCopyable> vec;
    vec.push_back(move(nc));
```

Here's the definition of NonCopyable:

```
class NonCopyable final {
public:
    const std::unique_ptr<string> data;
};
```

The error message is `Call to implicitly-deleted copy constructor of NonCopyable`.

How can I add NonCopyable elements to my vector while being able to signal that the embedded data field is immutable?

---

**Update**: my current solution is: (i) make `data` non-const; (ii) make it private; (iii) add a const function to expose `data`.

Comment: Did you even write a move constructor? Please show the definition of `NonCopyable`.

Comment: @Brian That's the cause. I thought that there's a default move constructor.

Comment: Not an answer to your question, but also take a look at `emplace_back` which often (but not always) eliminates the need for `push_back` with `move`.

Comment: @Fabian: There should be. You are either doing something to inhibit its generation, or your compiler is not fully compliant. What is clang 6.0? The latest version of clang is 3.7.

Comment: @BenjaminLindley I'm a `clang` newbie but here's what I see when I typed `clang --version`

`    Apple LLVM version 6.0 (clang-600.0.57) (based on LLVM 3.5svn)
    Target: x86_64-apple-darwin14.1.0
    Thread model: posix
`

Comment: Okay, well I guess that's Apple's own fork of LLVM (as you can see, it's based on LLVM 3.5). Anyway, I doubt that's the problem, because I'm quite sure that Clang 3.5 fully implements C++11. So the problem must be something you're doing to inhibit the generation of the move constructor.

Comment: And there it is. You made the `unique_ptr` const. It can't be moved if it's const.

Comment: @BenjaminLindley It is due to the const field in my NonCopyable definition. If I remove the const modifier, it works. How can I signal that this field is immutable then?

Comment: @Fabian: You'll have to be more clear about what you mean by immutable. Because if you want to allow it to be moved, then that sort of goes against immutability.

Comment: @BenjaminLindley I want to create a collection of read-only elements. That's all. Think of it as a dataset. I want to be able to read data and add to a vector; but once the dataset creation is done, I don't want any users of it to modify its contents.

Comment: Then make your vector const. You can start with a non-const vector, add all your elements, and when you've got it in the state you want, use it to initialize a const vector. Or you can keep a non-const vector as a private member of a class, but restrict access to it by a function which returns a const reference to it.

Comment: Using vector is just one **in-memory** implementation of an abstract dataset class. Another implementation is streaming, which has no vector at all. So I still desire each element to be readonly.

Comment: @DavidSchwartz I don't get your point yet. Even if I define a move ctor, how can I move data without violating the const-ness of data?

Comment: @DavidSchwartz `const_cast` exists to work around const-incorrect interfaces that don't actually attempt to modify the data (e.g., a `strlen` that takes `char *`); attempting to actually modify a `const` object is always UB.

Answer (score 2):

Your `NonCopyable` class does not have a move constructor. Define one.

The code shown should function correctly.

Comment: Just figured out that the problem is due to the const modifier of a field in my NonCopyable.